# Spring Integration - Stop Inbound Adapter - Exception observed

Tags: java, spring-integration

Using Spring Integration SFTP feature, and Inbound Channel Adapter, remote files are downloaded for processing.

While I use following start and stop routine to start/stop inbound channel adapter.

```java
    public void startInboundAdapter() throws ApplicationException {
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter streamInboundAdapter = appContext.getBean("streamInboundAdapter", SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
        streamInboundAdapter.start();
    }

    public void stopInboundAdapter() throws ApplicationException {
        SourcePollingChannelAdapter streamInboundAdapter = appContext.getBean("streamInboundAdapter", SourcePollingChannelAdapter.class);
        streamInboundAdapter.stop();
    }
```

But I observe an exception after stop inbound adapter is called after all files processing is done. I am stuck here and looking out for a solution, please suggest.

Stacktrace

```java
2020-08-15 15:44:24.298  INFO 9976 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.i.e.SourcePollingChannelAdapter      : stopped bean 'streamInboundAdapter'
2020-08-15 15:44:24.298 ERROR 9976 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'aggregatorFactoryBean'; defined in: 'class path resource [com/config/SFTPConfig.class]'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMethodMetadata@40dd3977']; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Interrupted while obtaining lock; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=sftp-inbound\upload_file.csv.bburpt.xls, headers={file_remoteHostPort=sftp.bloomberg.com:22, file_name=upload_file.csv.bburpt.xls, file_remoteDirectory=//report, file_originalFile=sftp-inbound\upload_file.csv.bburpt.xls, id=615015fe-b403-d247-c86e-f026a6ab3ad2, file_relativePath=upload_file.csv.bburpt.xls, file_remoteFile=upload_file.csv.bburpt.xls, timestamp=1597520532363}]
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:187)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.handleRequestMessage(ReplyProducingMessageHandlerWrapper.java:49)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:127)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:403)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:234)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:396)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:380)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:328)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:275)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:272)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Interrupted while obtaining lock; nested exception is java.lang.InterruptedException
    at org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore.completeGroup(SimpleMessageStore.java:426)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AggregatingMessageHandler.afterRelease(AggregatingMessageHandler.java:80)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.processMessageForGroup(AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.java:503)
    at org.springframework.integration.aggregator.AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractCorrelatingMe ssageHandler.java:471)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:170)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1261)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:317)
    at org.springframework.integration.store.SimpleMessageStore.completeGroup(SimpleMessageStore.java:412)
    ... 35 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop is immediate and if you have an in-process task that is interruptible, it will be interrupted.

Please add a new feature suggestion [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues).

We should either implement `Pausable` allowing you to wait until it's paused before stopping, or add an "orderly" option for stop.

Comment: Another way is to use a `executor` option for the poller, so any messages are handed to a separate thread an an interrupt of the polling task won't affect the message processing.

Comment: Also looks like this concern is related to: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-3118